# Which licenses are required for developing an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I see two possible licenses you might need for iPhone application development. The Company Developer and the Enterprise Developer. When might I need one or the other or both?

Comment: I assume you meant to tag this as iPhone, not iHone :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you building in-house apps for your company? You'll want to enroll in the Enterprise Developer Program.

Are you building apps, whether as yourself or as an iPhone development company, for putting up on the App Store for the public to use? You'll want to enroll in the Standard Developer Program, as either an individual or a company respectively.

Comment: Here's the link to Apple's summary: http://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/